# how can i control the Phone call?

Tags: iphone

I am new to iphone. now i am doing one baby monitoring project. My part is controlling sound like if the baby was crying that automatically call to that baby's mom mobile number.

So here i did all works, but if baby was crying that will call automatically from application to baby's mom mobile number.

But after reach the mobile number the application was end. so how can i rectify this problem. that means if suppose she stop the call it will goes to the application.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Iphone did not allow multitasking before version 4.x of the iOS. This means that when the phone app launches your application is closed. So it will not be possible pre iOS 4.x. For iOS 4.x You can keep your application running but there is still no way to bring your application to the foreground automatically. What you *can* do (in any version) is present the user with a notification to take you back to your app but the user has to opt in and touch the notification.